# making sense of what appears to be putting a type into a function in ReasonML: a styling convention or a syntax sugar?

Tags: types, reason, reason-react

I'm trying to learn ReasonML and come across this line in [the source of Reason React Hacker News](https://github.com/reasonml-community/reason-react-hacker-news) (`src/CommentList.re`):

```
type action =
  | Toggle(option(string));
```

where the next occurrence of `action` is as a parameter in the function `reducer`:

```
reducer: (action, state) =>
  switch action {
  | Toggle(commentId) =>
    ReasonReact.Update({
      collapsed_comments: toggleComment(state.collapsed_comments, commentId)
    })
  }
```

I have gone through the [docs](https://reasonml.github.io/docs/) but don't see any mention of such construct or practice (maybe I miss it?). Is this simply a styling convention of having a parameter and a type sharing the same name and then relying on the type inference to match the parameter `action` with the type `action`? Or is there some kind of syntax sugar going on here?

Why not make it less confusing by explicitly naming the type `actionType`? Or is the act of having a type and a parameter the same name some sort of emerging style convention in the Reason community?

Comment: Types and values live in separate namespaces, so the same name won't cause a clash. You learn to parse them as one or the other when reading the code, depending on context. This is an old convention in OCaml, you will often see code like `let f(int) = int + 1;`

Comment: @Yawar I see! Thanks. So it's some sort of OCaml artifact then!

Answer (score 0):

From the [ReasonReact docs](https://reasonml.github.io/reason-react/docs/en/state-actions-reducer.html):

> There's a user-defined type called action, named so by convention. It's a variant of all the possible state transitions in your component.

So you might rename it to `actionType` if you want (and I'd argue that might be more clear). The type in the reducer is inferred and does not depend on the type name.